# C programming, Is this an infinite loop?

Tags: c

What would happen if the follow lines were a part of a compiled program?

```
void main() {
    int x = 5;
    while (x == 5); 
}//end main
```

I believe it is, I have compiled it, and the screen just stays the same, I also tried to add after the while statement

```
int y = 10;
printf("%i", y);
```

and then end main. However it never prints. So I am fairly certain that its an infinite loop but I would just like to be sure.

Comment: How would that loop exit unless `x` changes? Theoretically if you run this long enough you'll get a bit flip error from a cosmic ray, but the odds of that are really low. It could take 1000 years to happen.

Comment: Please write your full source code for us to give you a better answer, Right now whatever we say will be unclear cause we have to make guesses on the code

Comment: thanks for the input! That was all that was available to me from the question in my homework. And I did do some research, however the stuff I came across was beyond me since I am just in my first year of c programming!

Comment: This code can terminate in C! C 2018 6.5 5 says “A loop that, outside of the *for-init-statement* in the case of a `for` statement,
— makes no calls to library I/O functions, and
— does not access or modify volatile objects, and
— performs no synchronization operations (1.10) or atomic operations (Clause 29)
may be assumed by the implementation to terminate.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, but it could actually leave the loop in some scenarios:

- There is a thread that changes the x variable.
- An external program modifies the program memory.
- As tadman said, a bitflip occurs on the memory itself, which is very unlikely but also a possibility.

There must be other cases where the loop can end, but those are the ones I could think of.

If you're interested, you can try to do so with Cheat Engine to change the value of x.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, much appreciated. I'm not trying to change the value of X is was just a homework question and that was all the info given to me. Thanks for extra input though!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is an infinite loop since the condition to exit the loop will never be met: as the variable x is never changed inside the loop, the loop's condition will always be true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's an infinite loop. Remember, while the condition is true the while loop will continue. As 5 will always be equal to 5 the condition will always be true, even if you don't do anything inside the while loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
void main() {
    int x = 5;
    while (x == 5){
        printf("%d\n", x);
    } 
}
```

Use format %d for doubles

Comment: So we are not suppose to change the code, its a true or false. So I am not trying to fix the code. So by adding {} after the while would defeat the purpose of using the code. I appreciate your input.

Comment: I understand. The code above will visually show you what is happening. If your up for learning.